# A summation operation based on the Minkowski sum of two sets

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, convex-analysis

Let $S$ and $T$ be two convex sets in $\mathbb R^2$.

For every pair of  $y\in S$ and $z\in T$, define $x=(x_{11},x_{12},x_{21}, x_{22})\in \mathbb R^4$  by

$x_{11}= y_1+z_1$,

$x_{12}= y_1+z_2$,

$x_{21}= y_2+z_1$,

$x_{22}= y_2+z_2$.

We then obtain a set $X\subset \mathbb R^4$ generated by $S,T$ and the an operation defined above. However, this operation is not the classical Minkowski sum of $S$ and $T$, i.e.,  $(x_{11},x_{22})$ is the Minkowski sum of $S$ and $T$ but $x$ is not.

My question is that how this summation relates to the Minkowski sum?  Is there any way to compute the set $X$?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: To construct $X$, you scale everything in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by a factor $\sqrt{2}$ and then isometrically embed the result into $\mathbb{R}^4$ in two different manner: $$
\begin{align}
\alpha: & \mathbb{R}^2 \ni (u,v) \mapsto (u,u,v,v) \in \mathbb{R}^4\\
\beta:  & \mathbb{R}^2 \ni (u,v) \mapsto (u,v,u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^4
\end{align}
$$
$X$ is the Minkowski sum of $\alpha(S)$ and $\beta(T)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The answer is very helpful.